# Is it possible to run both Try and Catch in the same statement

Tags: java

This is an interview question asked to me.the question is:

**Is it possible to run both Try and Catch in the same statement??**

And i got confused about this, Can anyone help me to find the solution. Please tell me how to do it if its possible.

```
try{
System.out.println("try");
}
catch (Exception e){
System.out.println("Catch");
}
```

The answer must be

```
try
Catch
```

Comment: Throw an exception in the last line of the try block?

Comment: The question is unclear.

Comment: Hi, You can use finally block if you always want to execute it with try.

Comment: @DeveloperBuddy me too said the same but they just replied wrong answer :(

Comment: what do you mean by statement?

Comment: Both try and catch are *block of zero or more statements*. "... in the same statment" doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Dileep I guess question is misunderstood or not asked in well manner. Don't worry, hit the nail next time. as there is no need to execute both in same statement :)

Comment: @Pshemo i cant tell any example for this because its something that won't make any sense. But they just asked me this in an interview.

Comment: @DaveNewton Is the question clear now, as i have edited it. If not what more i must add..??

Comment: @Dileep Not really. What constraints were you given? How is this code being executed? Can you modify the code?

Comment: if you cannot answer that interview question, perhaps it is not the correct job for you

Comment: @EssKay Difference between quitters and winners is the winners do learn. Quitters will think that job is not meant for you and walk away. Winners will keeps on thinking till he finds out the solution.

Answer (score 4):

The catch will only process if there was an Exception that will be cached

To print out both a Exception musts be thrown after the System.out.println("try");

But this shouldn't be the case in regular situations...

```
try{
    System.out.println("try");
    throw new Exception();
}catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("Catch");
}
```

This would make no sense (at least to me) but give you the output^^

Comment: does this throw new Exception(); throws an exception..?? and what kind of exception does it throws..??

Comment: @Dileep yes, it throws an exception of Exception type, wich will be caught by the catch clause. this means that will print both try and Catch.

Comment: @Dileep - If you can't recognize what `throw new Exception();` means then you're not Java-literate, I'm afraid.  Hopefully you impressed the interviewer with other skills you have.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, you never reach `catch` unless the corresponding `try` has at least been entered.  So part of the `try` will execute.  But you will not reach the `catch` if the corresponding `try` completes normally -- there must be at least an infinitesimal fragment of the `try` clause that did not complete.

Answer (score 1):

ultimately, it's an if else statement
if this works, keep going, else catch the error

but the answer is no, they are written on spearate lines

```
try{...do stuff...}

catch (Exception e){    System.out.println(e.tostring());    }
```

hope that helps